# Show Boundary of a set under continuous mapping has same image as interior

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $U$ be subset of $C$ (set of complex numbers) such that $U∪∂U=C$. If $f:C$ -> $C$ is a continuous function such that $f(z)=0$ for all $z∈U$, show that $f(z)=0$ for all $z$∈$C$.

Since the interior of U already satisfies $f(z)=0$, I believe we only need to showcase this for the boundary of U. I tried approaching this by taking a point z∈U and by continuity of f, there exists a $\delta$ such that f(D(z,$\delta$) $\subseteq$ D(f(z), $\epsilon_1$)= D(0,$\epsilon_1$) for some $\epsilon_1$>0. I thought maybe there's a way to relate to the definition of boundary point of $U$:

Let $w$ be a boundary point of $U$, then for any $\epsilon$>0, D(w,$\epsilon$) $\cap$
U and D(w,$\epsilon$) $\cap$ ∂U are non-empty. But I'm not sure how to take it from here or whether this is the right approach.

Any hints or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z \in \partial U$ you can find a sequence $z_n \in U$ so that $z_n \to z$ and then $f(z_n) \to f(z)$ by continuity. As all $f(z_n)$ are $0$ and limits are unique, it follows that $f(z)=0$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the idea of 'dense'. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Meow I gave an alternative proof..

Comment: Thanks, I can see how the proof works. I have a follow-up question regarding this though. Is there any axiom/theorem that guarantees the existence of a sequence $z_n$ that converges to z? If this was an open disk, I could simply define $z_n = z - \frac{1}{n} $ but since the boundary somehow extends to the entirety of the Complex plane, I'm kinda confused if that $z_n$ is still valid or not.

Comment: @Meow As $z \in \partial U$ any ball $B(z,r)$ intersects both $U$ and its complement. Just pick $z_n \in B(z,\frac1n) \cap U$ for all $n$.